# Error en el mapeo fuente: Error: request failed with status 404 en archivos CSS y JS

Tags: php, javascript, css, codeigniter

Estoy haciendo una web, y me sale esos errores por consola. Antes funcionaba todo correcto, no le hice ninguna modificacion de la ruta nativa del proyecto, el proyecto esta en codeigniter 3, no se que pasa

> Error en el mapeo fuente: Error: request failed with status 404

[image: error]

Si alguien me puede explicar por que pasa esto, las rutas estan bien, cuando clickeo una de esas rutas me redirige al css/js

Este es mi directorio de vendor en assets assets

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los errores 404 se refieren a recursos que no están en la ruta indicada, simplemente verifica que los archivos están en la ruta, por ejemplo, llama la atención que se repite dos veces `assets`  ¿realmente tienes una carpeta `assets` y dentro de ella otra carpeta `assets`?

Comment: No, eso esta bien. Se que hay una irregularidad en assets/assets. Pero esas carpetas existen y son dos assets

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta una captura de tu arbol de directorio abierto con la carpeta `assets`? Los errores 404 son inequívocos, se trata de un recurso que no existe. Otra cosa podría ser que tu dominio sea `https` y esté refiriendo a `http` y el `.htaccess` haga redirecciones o cosas de ese tipo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EL mensaje no es un error grave, solo esta indicando que no se ha podido encontrar el sourcemap (archivo .map) asociado al recurso .js o .css (pero los archivos js y css si se estan cargando)

Normalmente, los archivos minificados tienen una linea final que indica la presencia de un archivo sourcemap:

Por ejemplo: en https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js su ultima linea:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Esto indica que hay un sourcemap asociado en https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js.map

EL navegador automaticamente trata de descargar este archivo adicional (no es escencial, pero sirve para depurar o acceder la fuente del codigo minificado)

Por lo tanto, puede que solo se hayan subido al sitio los archivos escenciales (`.js` y `.css`) pero no sus archivos `.css.map` y `.js.map` asociados. Puedes buscar la manera de incluir estos archivos en la carga del sitio, quitar esta ultima linea de los archivos, o simplemente descartar estos mensajes.